# How to pass JWT token in Metadata in Rsocket Client in Spring Boot

Tags: java, rsocket, rsocket-java, spring-rsocket

I have added routes and JWT token in metadata but while passing token from RSocket client to RSocket server it is adding extra bytes in token.

Client side code -----------

```
            ByteBuf simpleAuthentication = AuthMetadataCodec.encodeBearerMetadata(ByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT,
                    TenantContext.getCurrentToken().toCharArray());

            CompositeMetadataCodec.encodeAndAddMetadata(metadata, ByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT,
                    "message/x.rsocket.authentication.bearer.v0", simpleAuthentication.asByteBuf());
```

Server-side token when trying to claim it :

```
"token" : "�eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.xyz.demo",
```

As you can see when the token started there were some extra characters.

> Does anyone know how to pass the JWT token in metadata in the RSocket client using SpringBoot and JAVA.

Answer (score 0):

Can paste your a complete demo.

```java
rSocketRequester.route("...")
                .metadata(token,  MimeTypeUtils.parseMimeType(WellKnownMimeType.MESSAGE_RSOCKET_AUTHENTICATION.getString()))
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use *WellKnownMimeType.MESSAGE_RSOCKET_AUTHENTICATION* because BearerTokenMetadata.BEARER_AUTHENTICATION_MIME_TYPE is deprecated.

**RSocketRequester** bean configuration can look like:

```
@Bean
fun getRsocketRequester(strategies: RSocketStrategies): RSocketRequester {

    val authenticationMimeType =
        MimeTypeUtils.parseMimeType(WellKnownMimeType.MESSAGE_RSOCKET_AUTHENTICATION.string)

    //build you bearer token
    val bearerMetadata = BearerTokenMetadata(token)

    // add bearer encoder so you will be able to build auth header properly
    val extendedStrategies = strategies.mutate().encoder(BearerTokenAuthenticationEncoder()).build()

    return RSocketRequester.builder()
        .rsocketConnector { rSocketConnector: RSocketConnector ->
            rSocketConnector.reconnect(
                Retry.fixedDelay(
                    2,
                    Duration.ofSeconds(2)
                )
            )
        }
        // pass updated strategy to rsocket builder
        .rsocketStrategies(extendedStrategies)
        // pass your bearer token with up-to-date auth mime type
        .setupMetadata(bearerMetadata, authenticationMimeType)
        .websocket(URI.create("ws://localhost:8090/rsocket"))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The java equivalent of Petro Prydorozhnyi's answer. Important the `token` should not contain the `Bearer` prefix.

```
    String token = "";

    MimeType authenticationMimeType =
            MimeTypeUtils.parseMimeType(WellKnownMimeType.MESSAGE_RSOCKET_AUTHENTICATION.getString());
    
    BearerTokenMetadata bearerMetadata = new BearerTokenMetadata(token);

    RSocketRequester requester = RSocketRequester.builder()
            .rsocketConnector(connector -> {
                connector.reconnect(Retry.fixedDelay(2, Duration.ofSeconds(2)));
            })
            .rsocketStrategies(RSocketStrategies
                    .builder()
                    .encoder(new BearerTokenAuthenticationEncoder())
                    .build())
            .setupMetadata(bearerMetadata, authenticationMimeType)
            .websocket(URI.create("ws://address:7000"));

    requester.rsocketClient().connect(); //Don't forget to connect.

    Thread.sleep(10000);
```